What happens with Google account during email migration from Google to Microsoft 365?
My company is moving from Google Apps for Business to Microsoft 365. We have several users on Android devices signed in with their current business supplied Google based email accounts. After the migration to 365, what happens with their accounts signed into their devices? Are they still signed in, even though that email address is now a 365 address? Or does their Google account still function, they just don't get email there?
